# Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array, when processing two $_POST

Tags: php, arrays

I'm receiving the following error **Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array** when processing `$_POST['cpl']`, although `$_POST['add']` works fine

```
if (is_array($_POST['add'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['add'] as $key => $value) $_POST['add'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $en = array_merge($en, $_POST['add']);
}

if (is_array($_POST['cpl'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['cpl'] as $key => $value) $_POST['cpl'][$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $cp = '';
    $cp = array_merge($cp, $_POST['cpl']);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because `$cp` is a string (you explicitly defined it that way).

```
$cp = ''; // <-- empty string
$cp = array_merge($cp, $_POST['cpl']);
```

should be:

```
$cp = array(); // <--now it's an array
$cp = array_merge($cp, $_POST['cpl']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You have these lines:

```
$cp = '';
$cp = array_merge($cp, $_POST['cpl']);
```

It's self-explanatory: `$cp` is a string first, the error is simply about this fact. Initialize it with `array()` instead.