# Remove key and value from associative array inside of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a little bit chaotic problem... As you can see in code below, I have an `array`, which contains other arrays. It creates user navigation according to their roles. Navigation items are inherited and here is my problem. I need to set values for key `'dokumenty'` in the lowest role `EXPERT`, than it shouldn't be visible for roles `REPORTER` and `REFERENT` and than again visible for `EDITOR`. So I am sharing `EXPERT` and `REPORTER` code, where I tried to remove values for `'dokumenty'`, but it threw me an error with `array_merge()`... I will be glad for any help, how to remove row with `'dokumenty'` key. I think I shouldn't share whole `return`, because it's quite long.

```
     return array(
         AuthRoleEnum::EXPERT => array(
            'prehled' => array('order' => 1, 'href' => ':Dashboard:Default:default', 'label' => 'Prehled', 'ico' => 'fa fa-th-list'),
            'pozemky' => array('order' => 3, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Pozemky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 1, 'href' => ':Land:List:default', 'label' => 'Seznam pozemku', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o'),
                array('order' => 2, 'href' => ':Land:List:selected', 'label' => 'Muj vyber', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o'),
            )),
            'mapa' => array('order' => 4, 'href' => ':Map:Default:default', 'label' => 'Mapa', 'ico' => 'fa fa-globe'),
            'dokumenty' => array('order' => 8, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Dokumenty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-newspaper-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 12, 'href' => ':ExpertReview:ContractsList:default', 'label' => 'Posudky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-folder'),
            )),
        ),
        AuthRoleEnum::REPORTER => array(
            'dokumenty' => null,
            'workflow' => array('order' => 20, 'href' => ':Construction:List:workflow', 'label' => 'Workflow', 'ico' => 'fa fa-cubes'),
        ),
        AuthRoleEnum::REFERENT => array(
            'stavby' => array('order' => 2, 'href' => ':Construction:List:default', 'label' => 'Stavby', 'ico' => 'fa fa-road', 'nodes' => [
                ['order' => 1, 'href' => ':Construction:List:default', 'label' => 'Seznam staveb', 'ico' => 'fa fa-road']
            ]),
            'kontakty' => array('order' => 9, 'href' => ':Contact:List:default', 'label' => 'Kontakty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-user', 'nodes' => []),
            'dokumenty' => array('order' => 8, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Dokumenty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-newspaper-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 9, 'href' => ':Document:List:default', 'hrefArgs' => array('landId' => null), 'label' => 'Seznam dokumentu', 'ico' => 'fa fa-newspaper-o'),
            )),
        ),
        AuthRoleEnum::EDITOR => array(
            'alarmy' => array('order' => 5, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Alarmy', 'ico' => 'fa fa-bell-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 6, 'href' => ':Alarm:List:default', 'label' => 'Seznam alarmu', 'ico' => 'fa fa-bell-o', 'class' => 'alarm-menu-field')
            )),
            'dokumenty' => array('order' => 8, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Dokumenty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-newspaper-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 10, 'href' => ':InsertionCadastral:GenerateInsertion:list', 'label' => 'Pozadavky na vklad do KN', 'ico' => 'fa fa-cloud-upload'),
                array('order' => 11, 'href' => ':Document:GenerateDocx:firstStep', 'label' => 'Generovani dokumentu', 'ico' => 'fa fa-pencil-square', 'class' => 'show-in-modal'),
                array('order' => 12, 'href' => ':ExpertReview:ContractsList:default', 'label' => 'Posudky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-folder'),
            )),
            'fronta' => array('order' => 15, 'href' => ':Queue:List:default', 'label' => '', 'ico' => 'fa fa-circle', 'class' => 'queue-menu-field'),
            'pozemky' => array('order' => 3, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Pozemky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 3, 'href' => ':Land:Comment:list', 'label' => 'Parcely s poznamkou', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o'),
                array('order' => 4, 'href' => ':BuildingObject:List:default', 'label' => '_T_MAIN_MENU_TITLE_BUILDING_OBJECT', 'ico' => 'fa fa-building')
            )),
        ),
        AuthRoleEnum::ADMIN => array(
            'stavby' => array('order' => 2, 'href' => ':Construction:List:default', 'label' => 'Stavby', 'ico' => 'fa fa-road', 'nodes' => [
                ['order' => 2, 'href' => ':Construction:UserActivity:default', 'label' => 'Aktivita uzivatelu', 'ico' => 'fa fa-user']
            ]),
            'system' => array('order' => 10, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'System', 'ico' => 'fa fa-cog', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 4, 'href' => ':Setting:UserConstruction:default', 'label' => 'Sprava opravneni uzivatelu a staveb', 'ico' => 'fa fa-building-o'),
                array('href' => ':Setting:User:default', 'label' => 'Uzivatelske ucty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-list')
            )),
            'alarmy' => array('order' => 5, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Alarmy', 'ico' => 'fa fa-bell-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 7, 'href' => ':Alarm:Edit:add', 'label' => 'Pridani alarmu', 'ico' => 'fa fa-pencil-square', 'class' => 'show-in-modal')
            )),
        ),
        AuthRoleEnum::SUPERADMIN => array(
            'kontakty' => array('order' => 18, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Kontakty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-user', 'nodes' => array(
                array('href' => ':Contact:List:default', 'label' => 'Kontakty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-folder'),
                array('href' => ':ExpertReview:Contact:default', 'label' => 'Posudkari', 'ico' => 'fa fa-folder')
            )),
            'system' => array('order' => 11, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'System', 'ico' => 'fa fa-list', 'nodes' => array(
                array('href' => ':Setting:Selection:default', 'label' => 'Ciselniky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-list'),
                array('href' => ':Setting:System:edit', 'label' => 'Zakladni parametry', 'ico' => 'fa fa-list', 'class' => 'show-in-modal', 'dataredirect' => 'false'),
                array('href' => ':Setting:ConstructionGeneratedSelections:default', 'label' => 'Sablony generovanych dokumentu', 'ico' => 'fa fa-list'),
                array('href' => ':Setting:ConstructionInsertedSelections:default', 'label' => 'Sablony vkladanych dokumentu', 'ico' => 'fa fa-list'),
                array('href' => ':Setting:WsUsers:default', 'label' => 'Uzivatele webovych sluzeb', 'ico' => 'fa fa-credit-card'),
                array('href' => ':Setting:UserLog:default', 'label' => 'Kompletni log', 'ico' => 'fa fa-h-square'),
                array('href' => 'changeDebugMode!', 'label' => $debugModeLabel, 'ico' => 'fa fa-gears'),
                array('href' => ':Setting:Changelog:list', 'label' => 'Changelog', 'ico' => 'fa fa-gears'),
            )),
        )
    );
```

Error while I try `'dokumenty' => null,`:

```
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array search
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I had to use shorthand for `if` and it works.

```
 'dokumenty' => (($userRole[0] == "EXPERT") ? (array('order' => 8, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Dokumenty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-newspaper-o', 'hidden' => 0, 'nodes' => array(
      array('order' => 12, 'href' => ':ExpertReview:ContractsList:default', 'label' => 'Posudky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-folder'),
      ))) : null),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right than you intent to remove the Dokumentry key from the array which can be achieved with the unset method **unset($arrayName['keyName']);**

If you just want to unset the value of Dokumentry in that array than you should do this:

```
 $yourArray = array(
         AuthRoleEnum::EXPERT => array(
            'prehled' => array('order' => 1, 'href' => ':Dashboard:Default:default', 'label' => 'Prehled', 'ico' => 'fa fa-th-list'),
            'pozemky' => array('order' => 3, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Pozemky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 1, 'href' => ':Land:List:default', 'label' => 'Seznam pozemku', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o'),
                array('order' => 2, 'href' => ':Land:List:selected', 'label' => 'Muj vyber', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o'),
            )),
            'mapa' => array('order' => 4, 'href' => ':Map:Default:default', 'label' => 'Mapa', 'ico' => 'fa fa-globe'),
            'dokumenty' => array('order' => 8, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Dokumenty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-newspaper-o', 'nodes' => array(
                array('order' => 12, 'href' => ':ExpertReview:ContractsList:default', 'label' => 'Posudky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-folder'),
            )),
        ),
        AuthRoleEnum::REPORTER => array(
            'dokumenty' => null,
            'workflow' => array('order' => 20, 'href' => ':Construction:List:workflow', 'label' => 'Workflow', 'ico' => 'fa fa-cubes'),
        ));
unset($yourArray[AuthRoleEnum::REPORTER]['dokumenty'] );
return $yourArray;
```

Or maybe your problem would be solved by using null instead of using qoutes ''.

```
return array(
     AuthRoleEnum::EXPERT => array(
        'prehled' => array('order' => 1, 'href' => ':Dashboard:Default:default', 'label' => 'Prehled', 'ico' => 'fa fa-th-list'),
        'pozemky' => array('order' => 3, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Pozemky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o', 'nodes' => array(
            array('order' => 1, 'href' => ':Land:List:default', 'label' => 'Seznam pozemku', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o'),
            array('order' => 2, 'href' => ':Land:List:selected', 'label' => 'Muj vyber', 'ico' => 'fa fa-flag-o'),
        )),
        'mapa' => array('order' => 4, 'href' => ':Map:Default:default', 'label' => 'Mapa', 'ico' => 'fa fa-globe'),
        'dokumenty' => array('order' => 8, 'href' => '#', 'label' => 'Dokumenty', 'ico' => 'fa fa-newspaper-o', 'nodes' => array(
            array('order' => 12, 'href' => ':ExpertReview:ContractsList:default', 'label' => 'Posudky', 'ico' => 'fa fa-folder'),
        )),
    ),
    AuthRoleEnum::REPORTER => array(
        'dokumenty' => null,
        'workflow' => array('order' => 20, 'href' => ':Construction:List:workflow', 'label' => 'Workflow', 'ico' => 'fa fa-cubes'),
    ),
```

If this doesn't help you, please provide the entire return, error message and try to define what you are trying to do more precisely.

The same error has been explained in this question [Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array, when processing two $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705733/warning-array-merge-argument-1-is-not-an-array-when-processing-two-post)

Comment: I've already tried this, but it didn't work. So I will add full return to my question and error which I get when I use this solution.

Comment: @HS1993 maybe you should give array() instead of null so that it's an empty array check out the link to the other question I've put at the end of the answer.

Comment: I've tried this too, but than I got this error message:
`Undefined index: nodes`

Comment: @HS1993 Well could you send me the AuthRoleEnum class and are you using any framework?

Comment: I have solved it! Look at my answer, that worked for me :) but thank you for help anyway!